# Trying to convert Lenovo ThinkPad to Android

Tags: rom-flashing, operating-system

My college administrator gave me an old Lenovo ThinkPad. He wiped everything out. It used to be Windows 7 and he put Windows 10 on it. Since then, I have had problems with it, so I bought a flash drive for Windows 10 and installed Windows 10 Home.

I'm trying to convert it over to Android, and with everything I try, people tell me it won't work.

Can you please help?

Comment: There is no official release for turning an Intel/AMD notebook into an Android device. There is Androidx86 but the hardware support is very limited and I have never seem a working installation of Androidx86 (only defect installations). In my opinion your best option is to test Chrome OS Flex which is the user installable version of Chrome OS. Chrome OS should have the ability to install and use Android APK files.

Comment: Your laptop is a good candidate for Linux perhaps you heard that somewhere and conflated the two?  Linux can be much less resource intensive and is a popular option over Windows on older hardware.  Most importantly, it is likely something you can manage.  FYI if you were to run android successfully on your hw it will put you in a very small elite group of enthusiasts  worldwide.

Comment: @Robert ChromeOS Flex does NOT support Android. See; https://support.google.com/chromeosflex/answer/11542901